# What invokerPackage is used for in swagger-codegen-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

[Here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) is a `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` description. What is a purpose for `invokerPackage`? And how it differs from `apiPackage`?

Comment: If you are generating code for multiple Swagger files then if you specify the same invokerPackage for all of them you will *not* end up with duplicated classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand their usage is to look at where they're used:

For `invokerPackage`: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/search?l=html%2Bdjango&q=invokerPackage&utf8=%E2%9C%93

For `apiPackage`: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/search?l=html%2Bdjango&q=apipackage&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Seems like `apiPackage` is used more on the server stub generator (e.g. springmvc).

I would suggest you to set a value for both to see if the auto-generated code meets your requirement/expectation.